# TextContentType(.newPassword) doesn't suggest password

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to get a strong password suggestion, when a user tries to register with email.
Email suggestion on the other hand does work perfectly, I get my email or Hide My Email.

My `SecureField` looks like this:

```swift
SecureField("Your password", text: $password)
    .textContentType(.newPassword)
```

But on my iPhone I only get suggestions for a Username, one being my email and the other being a username from me and never anything with password.

I have tried the things discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66620520/newpassword-for-securefield-to-choose-strong-password-not-working-using-swiftui), but I get the same error:

> Cannot show Automatic Strong Passwords for app bundleID:
> X.X.X due to error: Cannot save passwords for this
> app. Make sure you have set up Associated Domains for your app and
> AutoFill Passwords is enabled in Settings

I am only targeting iOS 17+.

What am I doing wrong here?
Do I have to wait some time for the `apple-app-site-association` file to be readable by apples server or maybe I did that wrong? But that would be a nextjs error from my side then, I guess..

Comment: You can use https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/ to validate your AASA

Comment: that actually helped a lot, thanks! @jnpdx